# How do I add a normal text with a Count fomula in the same cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried using this:

```
=countif(B2:B200, "<Open>")
```

And it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Or something similar to that. Basically I want to include the word "Open" and the number count of cells B2:B100

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Sure,  just use `&` as your concatenate function like this:

if your using your original requested function it looks like this:

```
="Open = "&countif(B2:B200, "<Open>")
```

if you actually just want the count of the cells with a value in them in column B use this:

```
="Open = "&counta(B2:B200)
```

Just make sure all the text  you want is enclosed in double quotes